# Google Play Services ImageManager and LibGDX... stopped playing nicely?

Tags: java, libgdx, google-play-services

This code was working for me to get the IconUri loaded into an ImageManager and to save the returned Drawable such that I could then load the Image into LibGDX.

Unfortunately, since updating to the latest library from Google (release 21 days ago), this method has stopped working, and I am getting no stacktrace or error message, other than a popup dialog stating "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped."

The really strange thing, Google Play Services does not stop (my game still processes messages received, and sent in the logcat) until I hit the "OK" on that dialog, then Google Play Services shuts down.

I would go back to the old version of the libary, but this new one also is acting much more well behaved with RealTimeReliable messages being sent and received.

Can anyone see why this would stop working with the new library?

Also, if anyone has any feedback on any other way of getting a player avatar loaded into Android, and then saved to the "local" directory for libGDX such that it can be pulled in and put in as a Drawable in libGDX, it would be much appreciated!

Also, note

```
@Override
public void requestPic(final String participantID){
    //try to pull the pic out
    dLog("attempting to request picture");
    if(CheckRoomisDisconnected()) {
        return;
    }
    for (final Participant p : mRoomCurrent.getParticipants()) {
        if (p.getParticipantId() == participantID){
            dLog("found matching particpantID");
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    //@Override
                    public void run(){
                        ImageManager IM = ImageManager.create(activityContext);
                        IM.loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageLoaded(Uri arg0, Drawable drawable) {
                                dLog("Holy Moly it seems to work");
                                if(drawable == null) {
                                    mGHInterface.picLoaded(participantID);
                                } else {
                                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
                                        try {
                                               FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("pic" + participantID + ".png", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                                               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                                               mGHInterface.picLoaded(participantID);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                             dLog(e.getStackTrace().toString());
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }, p.getIconImageUri());
                    }
                });
                }catch (final Exception ex){
                    dLog(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To follow up, I went back to the previous version (I think, cannot see how to get the version number for the SDK) by overwriting the BaseGameUtils and google-play-services_lib in Eclipse, and sure enough, it is back to working a-ok...  I do like the new version for its much better debugging statements, and more reliable messaging... but I'm stumped on how else to get URI's to decode without the whole thing crashing down.... (the old version does not have the OnP2PConnected nor OnP2PDiconnected methods)

Comment: Any other suggestion? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Was finally rectified (for me and a few others) with REV 12 of GPS